# Nginx and gunicorn are working fine, but site cannot be connected. How can I solve this problem?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, nginx, gunicorn

I am not good in English. I hope you understand.

I want to deploy the django project using AWS EC2.
(instance settings: Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS ... , t2 micro) + RDS + Gunicorn + Nginx

I finished all the setup of ec2.
Python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 works fine.

gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 Backend.wsgi:application works fine too.

But when sudo systemctl gunicorn start, when I connect to http://{mypublic IPv4}, the site cannot be connected.

my /etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service

```
(venv) ubuntu@ip-172-31-32-142:~/diary-with-pet/Backend$ cat /etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service
```

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=ubuntu
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/diary-with-pet/Backend/Backend
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/diary-with-pet/Backend/venv/bin/gunicorn \
        --workers 3 \
        --bind unix:/home/ubuntu/diary-with-pet/Backend/run/gunicorn.sock \
        --workers 3 --bind 0.0.0.0:8000  Backend.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

when I start gunicorn,

```
(venv) ubuntu@ip-172-31-32-142:~/diary-with-pet/Backend$ sudo systemctl start gunicorn
(venv) ubuntu@ip-172-31-32-142:~/diary-with-pet/Backend$ sudo systemctl enable gunicorn
(venv) ubuntu@ip-172-31-32-142:~/diary-with-pet/Backend$ sudo systemctl status gunicorn
```

```
● gunicorn.service - gunicorn daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service; enabled; vendor preset:
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2021-04-19 05:15:22 UTC; 1 day 5h ago
 Main PID: 9679 (gunicorn)
    Tasks: 4 (limit: 1140)
   CGroup: /system.slice/gunicorn.service
           ├─9679 /home/ubuntu/diary-with-pet/Backend/venv/bin/python3 /home/ubu
           ├─9700 /home/ubuntu/diary-with-pet/Backend/venv/bin/python3 /home/ubu
           ├─9702 /home/ubuntu/diary-with-pet/Backend/venv/bin/python3 /home/ubu
           └─9703 /home/ubuntu/diary-with-pet/Backend/venv/bin/python3 /home/ubu

Apr 19 05:15:22 ip-172-31-32-142 systemd[1]: Started gunicorn daemon.
Apr 19 05:15:22 ip-172-31-32-142 gunicorn[9679]: [2021-04-19 05:15:22 +0000] [96
Apr 19 05:15:22 ip-172-31-32-142 gunicorn[9679]: [2021-04-19 05:15:22 +0000] [96
Apr 19 05:15:22 ip-172-31-32-142 gunicorn[9679]: [2021-04-19 05:15:22 +0000] [96
Apr 19 05:15:22 ip-172-31-32-142 gunicorn[9679]: [2021-04-19 05:15:22 +0000] [97
Apr 19 05:15:22 ip-172-31-32-142 gunicorn[9679]: [2021-04-19 05:15:22 +0000] [97
Apr 19 05:15:23 ip-172-31-32-142 gunicorn[9679]: [2021-04-19 05:15:23 +0000] [97
lines 1-18/18 (END)
```

- nginx work fine too

```
(venv) ubuntu@ip-172-31-32-142:~/diary-with-pet/Backend$ sudo rm -f /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
(venv) ubuntu@ip-172-31-32-142:~/diary-with-pet/Backend$ sudo rm -f /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
(venv) ubuntu@ip-172-31-32-142:~/diary-with-pet/Backend$ sudo service nginx restart
(venv) ubuntu@ip-172-31-32-142:~/diary-with-pet/Backend$ sudo service nginx status

● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: en
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2021-04-20 10:41:41 UTC; 6s ago
     Docs: man:nginx(8)
  Process: 19581 ExecStop=/sbin/start-stop-daemon --quiet --stop --retry QUIT/5 
  Process: 19596 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; (cod
  Process: 19584 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process
 Main PID: 19597 (nginx)
    Tasks: 2 (limit: 1140)
   CGroup: /system.slice/nginx.service
           ├─19597 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_pr
           └─19598 nginx: worker process

Apr 20 10:41:41 ip-172-31-32-142 systemd[1]: Stopped A high performance web serv
Apr 20 10:41:41 ip-172-31-32-142 systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web ser
Apr 20 10:41:41 ip-172-31-32-142 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed to parse PID 
Apr 20 10:41:41 ip-172-31-32-142 systemd[1]: Started A high performance web serv
```

- my /etc/nginx/sites-available/Backend

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name 15.164.212.81;

        location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

        location /static/ {
                root /home/ubuntu/diary-with-pet/Backend;
        }

    location /media/ {
        root /home/ubuntu/diary-with-pet/Backend;
    }

        location / {
                include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://15.164.212.81:8000;
        }
}
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name {my public IPv4};

        location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

        location /static/ {
                root /home/ubuntu/diary-with-pet/Backend;
        }

    location /media/ {
        root /home/ubuntu/diary-with-pet/Backend;
    }

        location / {
                include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://{public IPv4}:8000;
        }
}
```

and I do this too.

```
$ sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/Backend /etc/nginx/sites-enabled
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: It seems like everything is up and running. Have you checked the Security Group rules of the EC2? You need to allow inbound traffic on port 80. For testing purposes, edit the Security Group rules and add HTTP from `My IP` to allow access only from your machine. If you wish to expose your EC2 to the world, change `My IP` to `Anywhere`. Is that your case?

Comment: I allowed port 80 in the EC2 security group, regardless of location. However, the results have not changed.

Comment: When connected to the EC2, can you `curl localhost:80` ? Do you get a response?

Comment: I'm sorry to see you late. I got this response

`<html>
<head><title>502 Bad Gateway</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)</center>
</body>
</html>`

Comment: So it's not something in AWS, it's something in your application. Maybe it's localhost:8000 ? I'm not sure which port you expose locally in the EC2

Comment: I changed allowed_host in settings.py to public IPv4 in my instance. I don't know why this is happening. Thank you very much anyway.